# Ubuntu on Lenovo RYZEN shows Lenovo logo after grub

Tags: lenovo, amd-ryzen

I tried installing Ubuntu but after restarting and seeing the grub menu, it shows the Lenovo red logo and doesn't start.

Answer (score 1):

I tried again with Ubuntu 19.10 instead of 18.04.2 LTS and it works perfectly well.